# VLOOKUP only doing partial lookup even though the [range_lookup] is set to FALSE

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I am having a problem with VLOOKUP, it is only doing partial look up even though the [range_lookup] is set to FALSE. the data is something like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18fjaq6pQixoAbeLnD0pQwx5K53CW13vlk8KlyaYiLNY/edit?usp=sharing

uploaded the file to google sheets for better understanding of my problem.

I am looking for the exact value from Sheet2 but vlookup only does partial lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your question. The first two "N/A"s in Column C correspond to cells A2 and A4 in Sheet1. If I take those two cells and search for their contents in Sheet2, there is no corresponding entry found. Seems VLOOKUP is searching for items that do not exist, therefore?

Comment: I don't really know what's happening to vlookup, been working this since yesterday. Do you think it has something to do with the special char in the cell such as "/" and "*"?

Comment: can you verify the data in column A in Sheet1 is actually contained in Sheet2? You may have a data mismatch issue??

Comment: Anupam Chand - that is interesting. I wonder if that behavior occurs in google sheets and microsoft excel?

Comment: Does look like it I tried downloading the same sheet and by some miracle(or bug), the correct value of 0.238 was shown.

Comment: kinda hard to verify that one though since that is one of the purpose of the lookup, to check wether the sku is already in our database (sheet2)

Answer (score 0):

So I raised a question to Microsoft and got back this answer.
That is happening because * is being treated as a wildcard character. Try using this formula

=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"*","~*"),Sheet2!A:B,2,0)

Wildcards for VLOOKUP has been documented [here](https://excelchamps.com/blog/wildcards-with-vlookup/).